# Can I split my data based on the polygons in a different layer?

Tags: carto, layers, analysis

Carto has a built-in dataset with polygon data for UK administrative regions. I have put another layer over this, containing several thousand data points (postcodes). Is there an easy way to find out how many post-code points fell into each administrative region, or do the layers not interact in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can count points into polygons. On this [training material](http://cartodb.github.io/training/intermediate/cartocss.html#geometric) you have a couple of alternatives to counting points inside polygons. You can actually do more than just counting, on those examples you'll see that you can do other aggregate operations like averaging or getting the maximum value of one of the attributes of the aggregated geometries. Maybe you should follow the material from the beginning so you get a better idea of different operations you can do with SQL and CartoDB.